# Find pattern with Position

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I have a list `a = {L, S, L, L, S}` and I can find the position of of either `L` or `S` by:

```
Position[a, {L, S}]
```

But what if I want to find IF the a segment `{L,S}` exists?

Ideally, I would like to know how many such patterns exist and how many elements separate them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SequenceCases[a, {L, S}]
```

> {{L, S}, {L, S}}

```
SequencePosition[a, {L, S}]
```

> {{1, 2}, {4, 5}}

```
SequenceCount[a, {L, S}]
```

> 2

**Edit:**

Per default, `Position` searches all levels of an expression while `SequencePosition` does not. One can force `Position` to focus on the first level to gain a speed-up. Still, `SequencePosition` is a bit faster.

```
a = RandomChoice[{S, L}, 1000000];
ls = Position[Partition[a, 2, 1], {L, S}]; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming
ls2 = Position[Partition[a, 2, 1], {L, S}, 1, Heads -> False]; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming
ls3 = Flatten[SequencePosition[a, {L, S}]][[1 ;; ;; 2]]; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming
Flatten[ls] == Flatten[ls2] == ls3
```

> {0.353, 96256488}
>
> {0.283, 96256568}
>
> {0.192, 32998448}
>
> True

Apparently, `SequencePosition` profits from using packed arrays while (`Positions` does not in this case). So it is even faster to recode the dataset.

```
b = Developer`ToPackedArray@With[{L = 0, S = 1}, Evaluate[a]]; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming
pat = Developer`ToPackedArray[{0, 1}];
ls4 = Flatten[SequencePosition[b, pat]][[1 ;; ;; 2]]; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming
ls3 == ls4
```

> {0.031, 16000320}
>
> {0.090, 33021904}
>
> True

Since a really like sparse arrays, here an even faster method using `SpareArray` (notice that we need the recoded list `b` from above):

```
ls5 = Flatten[SparseArray[UnitStep[Differences[b] - 1]]["NonzeroPositions"]]; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming
ls4 == ls5
```

> {0.017, 16579184}
>
> True

`Pick` is essentially on par; sometimes it is a tick faster:

```
ls6 = Pick[Range[Length[b] - 1], Differences[b], 1]; // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.015, 24000568}
>
> True

Answer (score 6):

One way to approach this would be to partition the sequence into pairs and then find the positions of the pairs:

```
ls = Position[Partition[a, 2, 1], {L, S}]
```

which shows that the two {L, S}s occur at the first and fourth positions. To find the separation between the occurrences:

```
Differences[ls]
```

To get the number of occurrences:

```
Length[ls]
```

If there are no occurrences, then you will get 0.